# How to target entire JSF page to be blocked by p:blockUI / pe:blockUI?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, blockui, primefaces-extensions

The example demonstrates blocking of `<h:form>` by [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf).

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="true">
    <pe:blockUI target="form" widgetVar="blockBodyUIWidget">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:graphicImage library="default" name="images/ajax-loader1.gif" class="block-ui-image"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['blockui.panel.message']}" class="block-ui-text"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </pe:blockUI>

<p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" 
                 onstart="PF('blockBodyUIWidget').block()" 
                 oncomplete="PF('blockBodyUIWidget').unblock();}" 
                 update=":form:dataGrid" actionListener="#{bean.listener}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-check" 
                 value="Save">
</h:form>
```

This blocks `<h:form>` but **there is a template** with a header and a left side bar which are not blocked by doing so.

I have tried to block `<h:body id="body"> <pe:blockUI target="body"...` on the template page but that didn't work ending with an exception indicating, "*Cannot find component with the id body in the view.*"

So, how to target the entire page?

<sub>Although I'm using `<pe:blockUI>` of [PrimeFaces extension](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/), the same thing can be demonstrated by `<p:blockUI>` of PrimeFaces</sub>

Comment: i have one problem like yours, basically exists one page with one button and this button have one link to page 2. How to lock the page 1 during the load time for page 2?

i create this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26304582/3703397

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Give an id to your body and then reference it on the `block` argument of the `<p:blockUI>` component.

Example:

```
<h:body id="entirePage"/>
```

and

```
<p:blockUI id="blockUI" widgetVar="blockBodyUIWidget" block=":entirePage"/>
```

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to prefix `:` before the `id` in the target attribute of `<pe:blockUI>`, indeed, sorry. It should have been `target=":body"`. Thanks.

Comment: i have one problem like yours, basically exists one page with one button and this button have one link to page 2. 
How to lock the page 1 during the load time for page 2?